# Akka.net Test Kit Ask method

Tags: c#, akka.net

What is the best way to write unit tests for a method that uses `ActorSelection` & `Ask`.
If I was to unit test the below code how would I write my test?
I know this code is not doing too much by my code does some more logic before it does the `Ask`.

```cs
private async Task HandleAsync(GetData message)
{
    try
    { 
        var actorSelection = await Context.ActorSelection(Self, $"/*/{message.id}").ResolveOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        actorSelection.Ask<GetData>(message).PipeTo(Sender, Self);
    }
    catch (ActorNotFoundException)
    {
        Sender.Tell(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try mocking the actor this way

```
private TestProbe actor { get; set; }
actor = CreateTestProbe(); [available in Akka.TestKit]
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MockActor>().WithParameter("receiver", actor);
public class MockActor : ReceiveActor
{
   public static IActorRef Receiver { get; set; }
   public MockActor(IActorRef receiver)
   {
       Receiver = receiver;
       Receive<object>((input) => Receiver.Tell(input));
   }
}
```

Comment: This will only work with very small programs, or simple actors. I agree you can mock actors with dependency injection, only disadvantage with Akka is you will end up with offline (test-) replacement code instead of actual unit tests, with your actual online Akka actors. Replacement code may contain bugs too. When your Akka actor runs multiple receive predicates in a later stage of development, each of these predicates has to take into account that the receiver is a test probe..